# Add a subview in a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am using a UITableViewController, I have resized the height of the table view and moved it a little down. Now I'd like to add a UIImageView above that table view but the only thing that I can do is add that UIImageView as a subview of the UITtableView of the UITableViewController, so that UIImageView is not above the UITableView and the image scrolls with the table view.

How can I accomplish what I'm trying ? Here is the code I've been using :

```
UIImageView *tabImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"temp.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:tabImageView];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe `UITableViewController` requires that its `view` be a `UITableView`.

In the past, I've worked around this by changing my view controller from subclassing `UITableViewController` to subclassing `UIViewController` and implementing the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. Then you can have your `view` be whatever you want, including shifting your `UITableView` down and adding a `UIImageView`.

Not sure if this is still the case in 4.2, though.

Answer (score 9):

### EDIT (December 16, 2013)

Just want to clarify that this is really not a great idea for many reasons, a bunch of which are listed in the comments. You should really be doing what Shaggy Frog is suggesting, or using View Controller Containment.

### Original Answer

You want the `UIImageView` to be static at the top of the `tableView`? If that's so, you need to set it as a subview of the `UINavigationController`, not the `UITableView`. Easiest way to do this is with `[self.view.superview addSubview:tabImageView]`. (although as Shaggy Frog said, it's probably best to change from a `UITableViewController` to a plain `UIViewController`, and create the `UITableView` manually)

If you want the `UIImageView` to be attached to the `UITableView`, so that when you scroll down, it disappears, you can just set it as the table header with `[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:tabImageView]`

Comment: I tried to use [self.view.superview addSubview:tabImageView] but the image does not appear anywhere when I am using that. Any idea why?

Comment: You probably need to set your frame.

Comment: Before adding `tabImageView` to the superview, try calling `[tabImageView setFrame:<CGRect goes here>]`

Comment: Won't adding it to the navigation controller's view mean the image view will stay visible even when another controller is pushed onto the stack?  This may not be desirable.

Comment: Setting the frame does not change anything, unfortunately! It is still invisible...

Comment: @aBitObvious Good point. Didn't think that one the whole way through. I would go with Shaggy Frog's method.

Comment: this works perfectly BUT the new "floating" view will NOT animate in properly with the view.  Also, don't forget to remove it manually when you pop!

Answer (score 0):

Take 4 cells in your static `UITableView` in `UITableViewController` with height of `44 PX` & width of `320PX`. Comment all `tableView` Delegate methods in `UITableViewController.m` file and put this code.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 170)];
    backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-cover-image.jpg"];
    [self.view.superview addSubview:backgroundView];

    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 960)];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ((indexPath.row)==0)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"one"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader.png"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }
    if ((indexPath.row)==1)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"two"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader2.png"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }
    if ((indexPath.row)==2)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"three"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader3.png"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }
    if ((indexPath.row)==3)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"four"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader.png"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Hope, It'll work.